# Validate Randomly-selected characters of User's Password

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out the best way to validate user password in Python.

Scenario: User will be asked to enter 3 random characters of their password.
User entry will be validated against stored password.
For example:

```
enter character 3 of your password:
enter character 6 of your password:
enter character 2 of your password:
```

If all 3 entries are correct display some message, if not terminate program

What would be the best way to do it? I'm struggling with it for a while now.

I have tried to store password in an array, and use `random.randrange(len(array))` and than if statement to validate user input and number of other ideas, but no luck so far.

Comment: Are you asking how to select n random valid indices? `random.sample(range(len(array)), n)`? We can't say what the problem with your current code is without a [mcve].

Comment: HI, I'm asking about the way to solve the problem. random.randrange(len(array)) was just one of many trials and errors. I'm just starting with programing :)

Comment: Then this is a very good time to learn that decomposing the problem and trial and error are very important parts of learning!

Comment: You'd be better off storing encrypted passwords and validating the whole input

Comment: @Sayse I agree, but how would the OP validate 2 characters potentiality contained in an encrypted password without decrypting the entire password?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex - Thats my point, they wouldn't

Comment: @sayse yes, no one would decrypt the password for verification.  They would verify that 2 hashes match.

Comment: @Sayse I'm unsure what the OP's real world scenario is, but I think that I understand what is trying to do in this question. The OP did state that they were new to Python (maybe even coding).

Answer (score 0):

Use random.choice(thelist)
`i = random.choice(range(len(thelist)))`

so now use `thelist[i]` and  it's i+1 character

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this task.

```
import random

stored_user_password = 'password'

user_input_prompts = ['enter character 2 of your password:', 
                      'enter character 3 of your password:', 
                      'enter character 6 of your password:']

# selects a random input from the list user_input_prompts
random_prompt = random.choice(user_input_prompts)

# prompts the user with the random obtained above
password_character = input(f'{random_prompt}')

# create a unique character set of the stored password
# ['a', 'd', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'w']
characters = set(stored_user_password)

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all
# all will return True only when all the elements 
if all((char in characters) for char in password_character):
    print('The characters provided are in your stored password.')
else:
  print('The characters provided are not in your stored password.')
```

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense, and certainly doesn't accomplish the task the OP describes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why the downvote? Please explain what is wrong with this code.

Comment: I fully understand number 1, number 2 might be true, but number 3 doesn't seem true, because the code works, but it could be improved, but I would be back in the number 1 boat again.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions, I really appreciate this. Like I said, I'm just starting to learn Python :)

Comment: @foxy_foxy we were all beginners at one time.  I continually learn something new everyday in Python.  Just keep coding, because that is how you improve.

Comment: @foxy_foxy  LMK what additional information you desire to fulfill your needs.  What is the real-world scenario for this?